# Why my Context menu have the background white?

Tags: java, android, listview, menu, contextmenu

I have a App in android, and i have a problem... i try to implement a context menu in a ListView and when I try to execute my app, it shows the context menu like this....

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcJjq.png

I dont understand why... this is my code..

This is how i create the menu

```
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/Aceptar"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_done"
        android:title="@string/detalle_autriza"
       />

    <item android:id="@+id/btnRechazar"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_delete"
        android:title="@string/detalle_rechaza" />
```

This is how i call the menu in my listview

```
Adapter adapter=new Adapter(this,jsonArray);
    tlList.setAdapter(adapter);
    registerForContextMenu(tlList);
```

And finally I call the menu in the method

(I overwrote the following method)...

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_list, menu);

    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

}
```

please, help me :(

Comment: can you post your manifest, please?

Comment: To Change Context Menu Background Color You Can Try

<style name="PopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/white</item>
</style>